# Display Form Fields Based on User Input

Tags: php, mysql

I'm displaying a set of rows here for every car I have in my database.
Each row has a form field where a logged in user can submit an offer.
When a user has made an offer for any car, the form field is replaced by a text displaying the value of the offer submitted.

What I'm experiencing, however, is less than ideal results.
If I make an offer for one row, great, the logic works. If I go ahead and make another offer for another row then the logic works, except the fact that the previous row now displays the form again.

I can provide more details if necessary but perhaps someone is familiar with this already.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

require("db-connect.php");

$display = "SELECT filename, car_id, make, model, year, mileage, vin, description, GROUP_CONCAT(filename) FROM scraplis_cars LEFT JOIN scraplis_images USING (car_id) GROUP BY car_id ORDER BY date_time DESC";

$dResult = mysql_query($display) or die('error:' . mysql_error());

$offer = "SELECT car_id, user_id, offer_id, value FROM scraplis_offers WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

$oResult = mysql_query($offer) or die('Error ' . mysql_error());

$oRow = mysql_fetch_array($oResult);

if(!isset($_SESSION['access'])){
    header("location:index.php"); 
}


?>

<?php if($dResult): ?>
    <table class="post">
        <thead>
            <tr>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['access'] == 0) : ?>
                <th scope="col">Images</th>
                <th scope="col">Make</th>
                <th scope="col">Model</th>
                <th scope="col">Year</th>
                <th scope="col">Mileage</th>
                <th scope="col">VIN #</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Offer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php while($dRow = mysql_fetch_array($dResult)) : ?>

            <?php  $str = $dRow[8]; ?>
            <?php $images = explode(',', $str); ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                <?php if(!empty($str)) : ?>
                    <?php foreach($images as $value) :?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="images/<?php echo $value; ?>" rel="lightbox[<?php echo $row['car_id']; ?>]">
                                <img src="images/<?php echo $value; ?>"/>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $dRow['make']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dRow['model']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dRow['year']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format($dRow['mileage']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dRow['vin']; ?></td>
                <td><span><?php echo $dRow['description']; ?></span></td>
                <td>
                <?php if($oRow['car_id'] == $dRow['car_id']) : ?>   
                    Offer pending approval - $<?php echo $oRow['value']; ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <form id="offer" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                        <input type="text" id="price" name="offer" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="<?php echo $dRow['car_id']; ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" name="price" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                <th scope="col">Images</th>
                <th scope="col">Make</th>
                <th scope="col">Model</th>
                <th scope="col">Year</th>
                <th scope="col">Mileage</th>
                <th scope="col">VIN #</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while($dRow = mysql_fetch_array($dResult)) : ?>
            <?php  $str = $dRow[8]; ?>
            <?php $images = explode(',', $str); ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="record" value="<?php echo $row['car_id']; ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" name="delete-car" value="Delete" />
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                <?php if(!empty($str)) : ?>
                    <?php foreach($images as $value) :?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="images/<?php echo $value; ?>" rel="lightbox[<?php echo $row['car_id']; ?>]">
                                <img src="images/<?php echo $value; ?>"/>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $dRow['make']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dRow['model']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dRow['year']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format($dRow['mileage']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dRow['vin']; ?></td>
                <td><span><?php echo $dRow['description']; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>          
    <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>        
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why not left join your offers table? you don't seem to have any control over which offer you're bringing back for a given row or loop, only returning them all for a given user? In the join you could fetch the most recent offer against that vehicle for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One **important** thing for security first:

**SEARCH:**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['access'])){
    header("location:index.php"); 
}
```

**REPLACE WITH:**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['access'])) {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
}
```

Take a look in the PHP documentation for `header()` or `exit()` - both describe the need (or security issue) of `exit()` here afair.

**To your question:**

You just have the first row of `$oResult` in `$oRow` - so you have (for example) 1000 cars but just one offer. You need to fetch the results of `$oResult` within a loop (`while()`, `for()`,... - what you prefer...) and then check wether you can find `car_id` (within `$dRow` also in the offers).

**code sample** (very easy for understanding):

```
<?php
// ...
// get the offers
// info: user_id would not be necessary here ;-)
$offer = "SELECT car_id, user_id, offer_id, value FROM scraplis_offers WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$oResult = mysql_query($offer) or die('Error ' . mysql_error());
$oRows = array();

while($oRow = mysql_fetch_array($oResult)) {
  $oRows[$oRow['car_id']] = array(
    'offer_id' => $oRow['offer_id'],
    'value' => $oRow['value']
  );
}

// looping the through the cars
// just the while()-loop based on your code
while($dRow = mysql_fetch_array($dResult)) {
 // check if offer exists
 if(array_key_exists($dRow['car_id'], $oRows)) {
   // H A V E an offer for that car ;-) - show offer details
 } else {
   // H A V E N O offer that car - show form
 }
}
// ...
?>
```

I hope I didn't get you wrong, made no mistakes (needed to get up early) and this helps you ;-).

Comment: Thanks, your solution is exactly what I needed. I have one more question and it pertains to printing out the values of the multi-dimensional array. After the if statement, I want to show the offer details which include the amount entered into the form field. How would I go about that? This is what I want to print $oRows[$oRow['car_id']]['value'] (at least I thnk so) but I receive an error saying the index doesn't exist. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to debug the array `$oRows` -> after `while($oRow = mysql_fetch_array($oResult)) ... ` make `print_r($oRows);` and print the result here ;-).